# Rules for a many to many (join object) association

Tags: firebase, firebase-security

I have an `Assignment` object that "joins" a `Project` to a `Service`. Many `User`s can work on any given `Assignment` (or a service for a project).

- `User` has many `Assignment`s
- `Project` has many `Assignment`s
- `Assignment` has many `User`s
- `Assignment` belongs to a `Project` *and* a `Service`

Here is a snapshot of some sample data for a visual.

```
users: {
  1: {
    name: 'John Smith',
    assignments: {
      1: true
    }
  },
  2: {
    name: 'Jane Doe',
    assignments: {
      1: true
    }
  }
}
projects: {
  1: {
    title: 'Project #1',
    assignments: {
      1: true
    }
  }
}
services: {
  1: {
    title: 'Service #1'
  }
}
assignments: {
  1: {
    service: 1,
    project: 1,
    users: {
      1: true,
      2: true
    }
  }
}
```

I'm trying to write a security rule so that **a project can only be read by users who are assigned to it.** So far I can figure out how to get all the assignments for a given project.

```
root.child('assignments')[data.child('assignments')]
```

When nested under a `"$project"` this rule will return an array of assignments. How can I detect whether *one* of these assignments has my user (`auth.id`)?

Or am I thinking about this the wrong way?

**Edit**: The more I think about it and try to implement this rule, the more I believe it's not possible using Firebase auth rules. I really hope that's not the case.

Answer (score 1):

There's not currently a way to search all children of a rule for a match. A simple answer here is to index users to projects, either by putting a list of valid projects under each user (just as you've done with assignments) or by maintaining a separate list:

```
/users/$userid/projects/$projectid/true
/project_assignments/$userid/$projectid/true
```

Either of these would allow you to write the security rule in question:

```
"projects": {
   "$projectid": {
      ".read": "root.child('users/'+auth.uid+'/projects/'+$projectid).exists()"
      // or
      ".read": "root.child('project_assignments/'+auth.uid+'/'+$projectid).exists()"
   }
}
```